# Extract multiple tables from PDF with multiple pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I wrote some Python code to extract multiple tables from a PDF with multiple pages and place those tables into an `.xls` file. The script has been running for some time; I assume it's because my code is bad. Here is my code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf

df = read_pdf("example.pdf", encoding='utf-8', spreadsheet=True, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)

for x in df:
    x.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    
writer = x.ExcelWriter('output.xls')
x.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: in the for loop, it appears you're trying to append the dataframe to `x` which itself is a part of `df` .. this appears to be running in an recurring loop.

What is `x` here and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have this 100 page pdf with multiple tables within it and i'm trying to make each table a dataframe and essentially append the tables to an excel file.

Comment: try creating an empty dataframe using `dfx = pd.DataFrame()` and then iterate through the pages reading them one at a time and then appending this dataframe to the empty dataframe. Once done for all pages, write the output to excel. P.S. I have never used `tabula` so far.